Streamlit/Seaborn confusion matrix partial data not showing
I am trying to plot a confusion matrix in streamlit.
The confusion matrix is supposed to show the following data.
array([[7, 6],
[3, 4]], dtype=int64)
Would anyone know why the lower quadrants' data labels (eg 3,4) are not appearing?

I am using seaborn 0.12.2.
The following is the sample code, just to produce the graphic.
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
X = np.random.rand(100, 10)  # 100 samples, 10 features each
y = np.random.choice(['Class1', 'Class2'], 100)  # 100 labels from 3 classes
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
y_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(y)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y_encoded, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=42)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, fmt='d', cmap='Blues', 
            xticklabels=label_encoder.classes_, yticklabels=label_encoder.classes_)
plt.title('Confusion Matrix')
plt.xlabel('Predicted Labels')
plt.ylabel('True Labels')
plt.show()


You need to upgrade seaborn.
